# How come Input field is not empty when creating it?

Tags: jquery, input, keydown

Up till now I always found an answer here at Stackoverflow to problems I encountered when coding Javascript/Jquery, but now I'm at a dead end.
Simple html and script, in which I create an input field.
This input field, on purpose, only shows up when I press the 's' key, but whatever I tried, the 's' also shows up in the input filed, which it should not do.
Only after I specifically clear the inputfield, the field is empty, but then the focus is lost...

Here is an example what I use (of course it is part of a much larger program) and you can see what I tried to get it to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Textbox-Test</title>
         <META HTTP-EQUIV="content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        function showSearchBox() {
            output = 'Please enter your search-word here: <input type="text" value="" id="searchBox"/>';
            $('#inputArea').html(output);

            //$('#searchBox').focus();
            //$('#searchBox').html("");
            //$('#searchBox').val("");          
            $('#searchBox').clear();        // clears the box (all the others don't), but only if .focus is after it, plus there there is no focus
            //$('#searchBox').empty();      
            //$('#searchBox').reset();
            $('#searchBox').focus();
        };
        function HandleKeyDown(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 83) {                      // s  show Search-box.
                showSearchBox();
            }
        };
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $(document).keydown(HandleKeyDown);
        });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Please press the 's' key to open the Search-Textbox.</h2>
        <div id="inputArea"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using `keyup` event instead of `keydown` might help

Comment: Thank you, this did the job, but because I use keydown for a couple of other keys, I choose the solution of gaemaf (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you delegate the keydown to the document, after appending your input to div the keydown is received also from this input field.

Check the event.target.id so that if you are not in the inpt field you can only add the search input box.

```js
function showSearchBox() {
  output = 'Please enter your search-word here: <input type="text" value="" id="searchBox"/>';
  
  $('#inputArea').append(output);  // use append instead of html
  
  $('#searchBox').focus();
};
function HandleKeyDown(e) {
  
  // if e.target.id is the input field do nothing
  if (e.keyCode == 83 && e.target.id != 'searchBox') {
    
    e.preventDefault();  // do not accept s char because you are creating a new textbox
    
    showSearchBox();
  }
};
$(function () {
  $(document).keydown(HandleKeyDown);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<h2>Please press the 's' key to open the Search-Textbox.</h2>
<div id="inputArea"></div>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, you 'opened my eyes', the e.preventDefault(); did the trick, and this then was the solution I implemented ! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In my laptop macbook pro the keycode for key s is 115. Think you should find it out in your case and then use the keypress event as:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
            var flag = true;
            $(document).keypress(function(e) {
              if(flag == true) {
              alert(e.which)
              if(e.which == '115') { 
                flag = false
                $('#inputArea').html('<input type="text" value="" id="searchBox"/>')
                $('#searchbox').focus(function(){});
              }
                
              }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <h2>Please press the 's' key to open the Search-Textbox.</h2>
        <div id="inputArea"></div>
    </body>
```

flag is used to trigger the success event only once

Comment: Thank you ! When my project is ready I sure need someone with a Mac to find out whether all the keydowns work as they should, because on Windows  the keycode for key s definitely is 83. Thanks.

Comment: Happy To Help ! :)